# Continuous galois cohomology with twisted profinite integer coefficients

Tags: number-theory, galois-cohomology

Let $k$ be a field that is finitely-generated over its prime field and $\bar k$ a separable closure. I would like to compute

$$
H^1_{cts}(\mathrm{Gal}_k, \hat{\mathbb{Z}}(1))
$$

Since $\mathbb{Z}(1) = \varprojlim \mu_{n, \bar k}$, we have

$$
H^1_{cts}(\mathrm{Gal}_k, \hat{\mathbb{Z}}(1))
= \varprojlim_n H^1(\mathrm{Gal}_k, \mu_{n, \bar k})
= \varprojlim_n k^{\times} / (k^{\times})^n
$$
Is there anything I can say about this inverse limit?